# How to manage multiple SQLite databases in a Qt C++ program?

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, qsqltablemodel

I am writing a program in Qt creator. I have a treeview and a tableview. Each time an item in the treeview is clicked, I need to update the tableview. The problem is that the tables realted to each tree item is different. Since the tableview works with SQLite databases, I have decided to create a database and a qsqltablemodel for each of the tree items and set the qsqltablemodel for the tableview upon each click on the tree item. I guess the tableview should update then. To implement this, I need at least 60 databases and models and am thinking if there is any issue with having mutiple databases and how to manage them effectively.

Comment: With  `qsqltablemodel`  you set your model  for one single table records  .. the problem is in your solution and you need more reading for Qt  QSqL ..

Comment: The problem is that no document has explained why having several models with their associated sql library in a single program is problematic. So, I really do not know how to update the table view in my program for various data sets.

Comment: _having several models with their associated sql library in a single program is problematic_ .. Not true , nobody said that! you need to implement different model for each table .. you cant have same logical model for different tables